# Zend Framework - Database Table Singleton

Tags: php, zend-framework, singleton, zend-db-table

I have found myself doing this in my code to 'cache' the work done when instantiating my `Zend_Db_Table` models:

```
if (Zend_Registry::isRegistered('x_table')) {
    $x_table = Zend_Registry::get('x_table');
} else {
    $x_table = new Default_Model_DbTable_X;
    Zend_Registry::set('x_table', $x_table);
}
```

It bothered me that this method isn't very DRY and it dawned on me today that a singleton pattern would probably be a better way to do this. Problem is, I've never written a singleton class. When I did some web searches, I found some offhand comments about `Zend_Db_Table` singletons, but no real examples.

I already have meta-data caching configured.

1. How do I make my `Zend_Db_Table` models singletons?
2. Are there pitfalls or downsides?

---

**Edit:** My reason for thinking a singleton was the answer is that I thought I could simply have the following calls in my code `$x_table = new Default_Model_DbTable_X;` and the single instance would be returned if it existed. If this is possible, I would prefer that solution.

Comment: What are you doing in your code that you need to instantiate multiple instances of the same table in the same request?

Comment: *(reference)* http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/singleton

Comment: I am building a CMS and the tables contain content.  Content blocks can be put into a page, and the page may have more than one of the same type of block in it.  Thanks for the reference!

Comment: you're welcome, but I still don't get why you need multiple instances of the same table instead of just passing around the first instance and doing multiple queries on it.

Comment: @Gordon - Sorry, I didn't answer your question correctly.  I don't need multiple instances, that's what my code above is trying to mitigate.  I (check for|store) the instance in the registry, which may or may not be there.  My post is basically asking for a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just manage the DbTables in some sensible place?  If there's no sensible place, create a DbTableManager class.  Something like:

```
<?PHP
class DbTableMgr {

  protected $_tables;

  public function getTable($classname){
    if ( empty($this->_tables[$name]) ){
      //assuming some things about class names for the sake of brevity elsewhere...
      $classname = 'Default_Model_DbTable_',ucfirst(strtolower($classname));

      $this->_tables[$name] = new $classname; 
    }
    return $this->_tables[$name];  
  }
}
```

Initialize the manager in your bootstrap and stick it in the registry.

Then:

```
<?PHP
//in a galaxy far, far, away
$dbtFoo = Zend_Registry::get('dbtMgr')->getTable('Foo');
```

So, you lazy-load the dbTable objects, and enforce a singleton-like behavior.

You could make the above static in various ways, if you wanted to.

Comment: Your `Zend_Registry` method looks good, but I'm intrigued by what you meant by "sensible place". It sounds like you're implying that the `Zend_Registry` is a second-best solution.

Comment: Zend_Registry is fine for this kind of thing.  I just meant that, depending on the application design, there might be a more sensible place to implement the dbTableManager stuff.  But if you're not sure, there's nothing wrong with just making a class like I've shown, and sticking that into the registry while bootstrapping your database stuff.

Comment: okay this is an old question but m curious. Why not just make it a signleton. If nothing else it adds convinience. UserTable::getInstance()->getUsers()

Comment: @Somesh Mukherjee - You could do that too, but in that case you'd need to add another layer to your class hierarchy to provide the singleton behavior for all *Table classes.  Zend_Registry is already there, and accomplishes essentially the same thing.

Comment: okay that is true. but i still think that's how Zend Tables should have been. The singeton pattern makes more sense than having a new object